# How do I report the parameters of a Panel VAR from my output?

Tags: r, time-series, panel-data, matlab, vector-autoregression

I have a panel data with 8 counties and 5 variables.

After running Vector Autoregression with lag (p=4)

I got the coefficient matrix I attached to https://we.tl/t-90sVrbokxx I was able to transpose it with the Matlab code in the link.

Each variable has equation has a total of 21 variables each with the constant.

My question is, how do I break this matrix into the components containing each variable, it's lag coefficient, per equation and for each country?

*I don't mind if the explanation is done in another software and not MATLAB*

Comment: Id just draw the IRFs for the variables of interest

Comment: How do I do that @Gukovic

Comment: Ive never done this in Matlab but I would start by checking here https://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/varm.irf.html